# How do I POST raw NSData as well as some NSStrings to my server?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsdata, nsjsonserialization

I have a large piece of NSData I want to send to my server, but I also want to send a string dictionary of string keys mapped to string keys.

How do I POST both in the same request?

Almost all guides show wrapping it in an NSDictionary then using NSJSONSerialization to turn it into NSData then POST that, but I can't have NSData and NSStrings in the same NSDictionary it just crashes, so I assume I have to keep it separate, but how would that look?

Essentially how do I serialize JSON into NSData and then also have a separate NSData blob with it?

Comment: You can first convert NSData to base64 String and then add to the dictionary. Then at server api end point you will need to covert that base64 string back to data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let body = NSMutableDictionary()
body.setValue("myString" forKey: "stringType")
body.setValue(data?.base64EncodedString(options: .lineLength64Characters) forKey: "dataType")
```

In this way you can have both data and string in the dictionary.
Here 'data?.base64EncodedString(options: .lineLength64Characters)' returns you a **string** with base64 encoding. So your dictionary contains only string and at server end you have to covert it back to data.

Hope it solves your issue